# For i in 0 that causes three exact errors

Tags: swift

I have a walkthroughdidscoll function and then an animation function that can help perform scaling, rotation and animations. Here is the code. Here is an image of the error i get.

[image: Error Image]

```
func walkthroughDidScroll(_ position: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) {



    for(i in 0 ..< subsWeights.count ){

        // Perform Transition/Scale/Rotate animations
        switch animation{

        case .Linear:
            animationLinear(i, offset)

        case .Zoom:
            animationZoom(i, offset)

        case .Curve:
            animationCurve(i, offset)

        case .InOut:
            animationInOut(i, offset)
        }

        // Animate alpha
        if(animateAlpha){
            animationAlpha(i, offset)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
func walkthroughDidScroll(_ position: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) {



    for i in 0 ..< subsWeights.count {

        // Perform Transition/Scale/Rotate animations
        switch animation{

        case .Linear:
            animationLinear(i, offset)

        case .Zoom:
            animationZoom(i, offset)

        case .Curve:
            animationCurve(i, offset)

        case .InOut:
            animationInOut(i, offset)
        }

        // Animate alpha
        if(animateAlpha){
            animationAlpha(i, offset)
        }
    }
}
```

this is the basic structure of a this type of for loop with an example:

```
    for index in 1...5 {
        print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")
    }

// 1 times 5 is 5
// 2 times 5 is 10
// 3 times 5 is 15
// 4 times 5 is 20
// 5 times 5 is 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses.

`for i in 0 ..< subsWeights.count {`

Comment: I have been writing C-style loops so long that I keep doing this as well. I get myself trained to skip the parens, and then I write a loop using `for (index, value) in array` syntax and go back to putting parentheses again for while. The coding habits of a couple of a few decades are hard to break. :/ Sigh...